# NestJS not watching in docker

Tags: typescript, docker, nestjs, windows-subsystem-for-linux, docker-desktop

Since upgrading Docker Desktop for Windows recently, my `nest start --watch` stopped working. It is not reloading anymore for changes (not watching). It does work outside of docker.

The current version of Docker Desktop: `4.15.0`. I tried reinstalling it without luck. The code is the same.

What could be the issue?

Comment: I do not recognize such an issue. Could you provide more context here? For example how exactly you use it with docker